# How do I change the order of the items in an arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist. For example
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

I need to change the order of the arraylist so that I can get

A = [2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7]. It means odd position item will be positioned in even positions and vice-versa.

Thanks

Comment: Ok, what have you tried to accomplish it?

Comment: Please tell us what you've done so far.

Comment: Have you already learned how to implement a `swap()` method?

Comment: Nope. The values can be anything. Just need to get the odd positioned values in even positions and even positioned values in odd positions. The number of elements of the array will be always even.

Comment: @DavidWallace - Yes, I realized that after my comment was posted, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach that assumes

1. Length of A is given as `A.size()`
2. Array A can be accessed by `A.get(index)` and `A.set(index, value)`
3. If your array is not even, the last element is left as-is

Is to swap values in pairs - like this:

```
for (int index = 1; index < A.size(); index += 2) { // Swap on even indices.
   // Swap values at positions index-1 and index.
   Object temp = A.get(index-1); // Save value before overwrite.
   A.set(index-1, A.get(index)); // First half of swap.
   A.set(index, temp); // Final operation for swap.
}
```

Edit: Changed `int` to `Object`, and used `A.size`, `A.get` and `A.set` instead of [] indexers as suggested by comments.

Comment: You can't use [] indexers, so use A.get(index) instead. +1 for method though.

Comment: User mentioned the values can be anything, so instead of int, an Object could be used. Also, the length can be determined by calling .size(). Should also mention it would be prudent to check the size of the array and make sure it's either even, or you make provisions for handling the odd leftover.

Comment: Adjusted my example to take your comments into account for a more complete approach.

Comment: Thanks. It is exactly doing the same thing that I needed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the following way:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

        System.out.println("A=["+a[0]+","+a[1]+","+a[2]+","+a[3]+","+a[4]+","+a[5]+","+a[6]+","+a[7]+"]");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length/2; i++) {
            int help;
            help = a[i*2];
            a[i*2]=a[i*2+1];
            a[i*2+1] = help;
        }
        System.out.println("A=["+a[0]+","+a[1]+","+a[2]+","+a[3]+","+a[4]+","+a[5]+","+a[6]+","+a[7]+"]");
```

Ask if you have questions about the code.

Edit: I missed the arraylist, but the principle is the same.